# Display admin configuration field by other field text value

Tags: adminhtml, system-config

In Magento2 admin configuration we can display field conditionally like below,

```
<field id="do_3Dsecure" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Activate 3DS Authentication</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>

<field id="enable_dynamic3DS2" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable 3DS2 Authentication</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <depends><field id="do_3Dsecure">1</field></depends>
</field>
```

It is Yes/No (1/0) and it is working fine with **depends** node. But in my case that dependant field is having text value, like below

```
 <field id="integration_mode" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Integration Mode</label>
                    <source_model>Mymodule\Test\Worldpay\Model\Config\Source\IntegrationMode</source_model>
                </field>
```

it is a dropdown field and it contains below below values

1. direct
2. redirect

So, is there any possible to display field based on this above text value by using **depends** node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<depends><field id="integration_mode">direct</field></depends>
```